# CDN fallback for Velocity JS and Velocity UI

Tags: javascript, cdn, velocity.js

I've set up sucessfully the fallback for jQuery and Velocity, but I don't know how to do the same with Velocity UI. I can access

```
 window.jQuery.Velocity
```

to see if it is there, how to check the same with Velocity UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [source of velocity UI](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.ui.js) you'll see that `/* Note: RegisterUI is a legacy name. */` comment.

So, use `window.jQuery.Velocity.RegisterUI` to check if it's present.

---

[Fiddle **without** velocity UI included](http://jsfiddle.net/anucjxut/1/).

Result in console: `undefined`.

---

[Fiddle **with** velocity UI included](http://jsfiddle.net/anucjxut/)

Result in console:

```
(index):32 (t,a){function e(t,a,e,r){...}
```

Comment: Oh. I was looking for "Velocity-UI", or similar. Works perfect. Thank you.